# Simple angular ment.io menu not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mention

Markup

```
<input type="text" 
   mentio
   mentio-id="'test'"
   mentio-typed-text="typedTerm"
   ng-model="myval"/>

<mentio-menu
    mentio-for="'test'"
    mentio-trigger-char="'@'"
    mentio-items="mentioPeople"
    ></mentio-menu>
```

Inside controller:

```
module.controller($scope) {
    $scope.mentioPeople = [{label: "Test"}];
}
```

The above code is not working (nothing happens when i do enter the '@' character).

If i embed the very same options as attribute directives in the input element, it works - see the following:

```
<input type="text" mentio
   mentio-id="'test'"
   mentio-typed-text="typedTerm"
   mentio-trigger-char="'@'"
   mentio-items="mentioPeople"
   ng-model="myval"/>
```

Why? What am i doing wrong in the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the `mentio-search` option is mandatory. The following

```
<mentio-menu
    mentio-for="'test'"
    mentio-trigger-char="'@'"
    mentio-items="mentioPeople"
    mentio-search="search()"
        ></mentio-menu>
```

will work.

Credits to **ronaldheft** [here](https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io/issues/151)